# Condominium Reviews

Tags: mortgage, real-estate

I am looking to buy a condo, but I am having trouble finding out information about the condominium complexes I am looking at, and knowing what information to trust.

Several of the places I am looking at have good reviews on google (over 4 stars with several dozen reviews), but I do not know if I can trust those because I think the people doing the reviews have a vested interest in the place having high reviews.
Even looking at the individual reviews to try and find people who used to live in the building and have since left seems like a bad strategy because if someone had a terrible experience they are more likely to leave a review than if someone had just a good experience, hence skewing the data. Furthermore, there are just not many such reviews of past departed residents anyways, hence my sample size would be too small.

Additionally, I cannot find any reviews whatsoever for one of the places I am looking at. Are there any good websites for reviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the purchase process, you should get some kind of document packet, containing both financial information on the condo association, and meeting minutes. Read the meeting minutes; that's where you run into issues like "that lovely creek in the back yard overflows into the crawlspace in heavy rain, and it can't be fixed because of environmental issues", or "there's plans for a 20 story apartment building next door, plunging your home into permanent twilight".

Online reviews are worth reading, but as you noted there's little incentive to actually reveal problems.